# React Native Download image from firebase storage to my assets folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I know how to get the URL for the image, but I use it so often that it doesn't make sense for me to keep using uri every single time. So what I want to do is download the image into my assets folder (Override the old one) and then use that one over and over again.

here is how I get the URL

```
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('current_company_list.png');
        storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(
          function (url) {
            // image = url
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          },
        );
```

but I cant seem to find how to download it to be used not as a uri anymore...

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript web client APIs for Cloud Storage don't provide a way to download an object locally.  If you don't want to call `getDownloadURL` repeatedly, then you could instead store it somewhere for reuse.  It's entirely possible that future fetches of that URL coudl come from browser cache, which is effectively local storage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I do only call once getDownload URL. But what I want to do is be able to download the image from that URL. in order for me to do this: 

<Image source={require('./downloaded_image.png')} />

instead of using uri

Comment: As I said, the Firebase Storage API doesn't offer anything for that. That url is all you get.